# Getting direct links to video

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, rest

I have some videos uploaded on viddler, now need the raw file/video link in mp4 format so i send it as a json rest API request to the android app,at the moment I can get the html links to it but I need this too, is such a thing possible? My website is in word press, and I am using the Viddler WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my wrong comment, A quick look at there [API documentation](http://developers.viddler.com/documentation/api-v2/). I think you would use [viddler.videos.getDetails](http://developers.viddler.com/documentation/api-v2/#toc-viddler-videos-getdetails) and after [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)'ing it access the value as:

```
$resp->video->url
```

or

```
$resp->video->html5_video_source
```

Which would be a url like:

`http://www.viddler.com/file/VIDEO_KEY/html5`

Or whichever one returns something like the following is what your after: (**Note:** I dont use there API, and it doesn't show the format of the url in the documentation):

http://www.viddler.com/file/d/48eaa1ff.mp4

Also there is a [Viddler PHP Wrapper](https://github.com/viddler/phpviddler/blob/master/phpviddler.php) that might make it easyier for you then writing your own wrapper for there API.

### Edit see comment,

By you supplying the link to the video, I can deduce my answer to:

Its not a direct link to the file; `a9fcd88d` is the id for that video. Your need to use that id as the *video_id* parameter, in the following API request (viddler.videos.getDetails):

`GET /api/v2/viddler.videos.getDetails.php?sessionid=SESSIONID&key=YOUR_API_KEY&video_id=a9fcd88d`

Its all in the docs link above, see click this link (notice the id) http://www.viddler.com/file/a9fcd88d/html5 your see its webm type or HTML5 fallback video.

But, your after `.mp4` version which is not offered as std, so your need to use that id(a9fcd88d) to get the mp4 version from that API result set, which I don't know the result of `$resp->video->url` response, **because its not in the docs**, else it would be easy to just parse the id and download in mp4 format.

Also they make a futile attempt to make it secure by the player being built through an iframe with javascript, obfuscation and a XSRF token but with some simple console and breakpoints its trivial to get to the actual path of the video and download it (fail...):

http://mynivo-vfs.cdn-ec.viddler.com/mynivo_1s219veo8r3sp77i3oaz90bwhjar3c.mp4?fd9f2a1c14aadf1069f046c16bf41e2b3776a6b320734cdc73d93c30ad8d0e26c7fa5d6ea6105bad4ec694d7af6126c6df817ecdfe80910ce08b938b90e4efc7de19e2b64be6fbfaa9ab32e29b3f

How long that key parameter stays active I dont know... (edit) actually couple of minutes later its now the following, so it is time based.

http://mynivo-vfs.cdn-ec.viddler.com/mynivo_1s219veo8r3sp77i3oaz90bwhjar3c.mp4?fd9f2a1c14aadf1069f046c16bf41e2b3776a6b320734cdc73d93c30ad8d0d2bf4206bd54f270ce83a6237e126803d96b8d90f53e539676c7518df3e497affdd3018bb2c364035984d1b934be221

Hope it helps, basically **use the API** to get the unsecured mp4 version url, which I presume will be in `$resp->video->url`

### Edit 2

But unless you want to *download the video*, you might as well use the provided embed code link in an iframe, for example.

```
<?php 
$video_id = 'a9fcd88d'; 

echo '<iframe width="100%" 
              height="100%" 
              src="http://www.viddler.com/embed/'.$video_id.'"></iframe>';
?>
```